# TortoiseSVN sublime 2 and Windows

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, text-editor, sublimetext2

Sublime 2 text editor seems to have an issue whereby when I right click and edit a file out of TortoiseSVN  and it opens in Sublime I can edit it. If (and only if) there is no other tab open it will allow me to save the file (in its temp location) and then SVN will commit it back in after propmting me for a check in note.

But...

If I have more than one tab open it will not allow a save and therefore will I don't get the checkin prompt and it does not go back into SVN. I have to open up Sublime, close all tabs, close Sublime and then right click and edi tthe file out of TortoiseSVN, save it and then it propmts again for checkin.

Has anyone seen this behaviour ? If so how did you fix it, or what other combination do you use ?

Comment: Have you tried to ask on the dedicated support forum? http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3

Answer (score 0):

TSVN waits for the editor to close before it tries to auto-commit.
If you have multiple tabs open and just save one of them but keep the editor running, TSVN can not know that you have saved the file and closed the tab of the editor.

It can only detect if the editor **process** is closed, not if a tab is closed.